# How to bypass ldaps in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008

I am trying to use a basic PHP page to create a new user in a Windows 2008R2 domain. However when ever I try to specify a password I receive a error stating that the server was unwilling to perform my request.

I was wondering if there is any other way to create a new domain user with PHP that will allow me to set the password of the user.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It's completely possible. You need to connect to the Active Directory domain using LDAP(s), and authenticate with it using a user account that has enough privileges to create/modify user accounts within that domain. There are third party libraries/projects that exist that could take care of some of the leg work for you, but without that credentialed account, you'll never be able to accomplish this.